# JavaScript - cannot add 2 numbers correctly

Tags: javascript, html, input, numbers, addition

I am simulating a calculator using Javascript.

Where a user can input 2 numbers in a given text box, and it will display sum, product, difference and division.

Here is my function-

```
function calculate(num1, num2) {
  console.log("First Number = " + num1 + " Second Number = " + num2);
  console.log("Sum = " + (num1 + num2));
  console.log("Product =" + (num1 * num2));
  console.log("Difference = " + (num1 - num2));
  console.log("Division = " + (num1 / num2));
}
```

When user inputs 1st number 4 and second number 3 i get this result:

```
First Number = 4 Second Number = 3
Sum = 43  // sum should be 7 NOT 43
Product = 12 
Difference = 1 
Division = 1.3333333333333333
```

Any ideas what is wrong here?

Comment: They are being treated as strings because you are concatenating them. Try using `parseInt()`.

Comment: but other operation work fine. It divides correct, subtracts correct, and multiplies correct

Comment: Because `+` is also used to concatenate strings, and it will do that if any part of the equation is a string.

Comment: Just make sure  string is not passed as parameters instead of numbers like calculate('4','3').Your code gives 7 if it is called with calculate(4,3)...It is giving 7 without parseInt for me.Tested in chrome and firefox

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because + is also a String Concatinater in JavaScript. use parseInt(var1) + parseInt(var2) it will work. also have a look on ---> [Javascript Operators](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp)

to understand the + operator.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you're taking in the numbers in a text box they're treated as strings, so the `+` operator will do string concatenation. The `*` operator doesn't mean anything in relation to strings, so the javascript engine will try to interpret the inputs as numbers.

You can use parseInt on the inputs to convert them to numbers, or use the html `number` input type.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
console.log("Sum = " + (parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2)));
```

or

```
console.log("Sum = " + (0 + num1 + num2));
```

also make sure you are calling the function like

```
calculate(4, 3);
```

and not

```
calculate('4', '3');
```

Answer (score 1):

At least one of your inputs to calculate() is string. + is defined for string so become 43. While */- are not defined for string and Javascript "cleverly" convert them to int.