# JS '+' operator does not carry out numerical addition from getElementById

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, math

I want to ask about JS operator `add` or `+`:

```js
function calculate() {
    var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1').value; 
    var myBox2 = document.getElementById('box2').value;
    var result = document.getElementById('result'); 
    var myResult = myBox1 + myBox2;
    result.value = myResult;
}
```

If I give numbers like `60` + `40` the result will become `6040` not `100`, can everybody explain that and tell how to fix it?

Comment: convert the values into numbers using `Number()`. the way you are doing it is that the string are combined. `+` in js is used to combine strings. you can have `Number(myBox1) + Number(myBox2);` . you can also `parse` like  `parseFloat()` or `parseInt()`

Comment: `+` is both concatenation and the sum operator in js,right now you are concatenating, convert the strings to number to use the sum operator

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript - cannot add 2 numbers correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26308704/javascript-cannot-add-2-numbers-correctly)

Answer (score 2):

```
function calculate() {
    var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1').value; 
    var myBox2 = document.getElementById('box2').value;
    var result = document.getElementById('result'); 
    var myResult = parseInt(myBox1) + parseInt(myBox2);
    result.value = myResult;
}
```

Cause `mybox1` and `mybox2` is `string`, So when you print `result` of value you just see `6040`. 
The solution is that you should convert `string` to `int` using `parseInt()`.

Comment: better explain what you did here

Answer (score 1):

They are actually strings not numbers. To produce a number from a string is to prepend it with+:

```
function calculate() {
  var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1').value; 
  var myBox2 = document.getElementById('box2').value;
  var result = document.getElementById('result'); 
  var myResult = +myBox1 + +myBox2;
  result.value = myResult;
}
```

```js
function calculate() {
  var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1').value; 
  var myBox2 = document.getElementById('box2').value;
  var result = document.getElementById('result'); 
  var myResult = +myBox1 + +myBox2;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myResult;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  Click the button.
  <button onclick="calculate()">Try it</button>
</p>
<p>
  Enter first number:
  <input type="text" id="box1" name="box1" value="1">
  Enter second number:
  <input type="text" id="box2" name="box2" value="2">
</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: hi ankita patel thats great thanks i get your code and running like flash thanks bro and thanks everybody

Answer (score 0):

Convert *myBox1*, *myBox2* value type from string to number. Use `parseInt(string, radix)` that parses a string argument and returns an integer of the specified radix (the base in mathematical numeral systems).

```
function calculate() {
  var myBox1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('box1').value, 10); 
  var myBox2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('box2').value, 10);
  var result = document.getElementById('result');

  var myResult = myBox1 + myBox2;
  result.value  myResult;
}
```

Comment: still can't.. the answer stil 6040

Comment: myBox1, myBox2 are integer since using *parseInt()*. So, the result should be `100` instead `6040`. Can you check again?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert to integer value by adding parseInt() function.

```
function calculate() {
    var myBox1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('box1').value); 
    var myBox2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('box2').value);
    var result = document.getElementById('result'); 
    var myResult = myBox1 + myBox2;
    result.value  myResult;


}
```

Comment: If the input is always integers, then this is OK. But if the input is something like 2.5 (not an integer), then everything after the decimal point will be discarded. Maybe better to use Ankita Patel's solution.

Answer (score 0):

The `+` operator is used for concatenation of strings in Javascript as well as addition of numbers.
In your case you are reading values of a field which come out to be `Strings` and not Numbers. Hence they are concatenated instead of being added.
To verify this you can use the below statement.

```
console.log(typeof(myBox1));
```

This would give you and output like `"string"` in both the cases of `myBox1` and `myBox2`.

Answer (score 0):

Well yeah, that will happen as the values of myBox1 and myBox2 are of String datatype, not numbers.So when you are doing myBox1 + myBox2 its concatenating the strings(i.e 6040) not adding like numbers.

The solution to your problem is to convert those string values into numbers by using a javascript method parseInt().

The corrected code is shown below.

```
function calculate() {
        var myBox1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('box1').value); 
        var myBox2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('box2').value);
        var result = document.getElementById('result'); 
        var myResult = myBox1 + myBox2;
        result.value  myResult;    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The value that you get is a string `+` operator will add (concatenate) strings, you need to convert them to number first, you also can check if the final result is a number or not. check below example :

```
function calculate (){
  var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1').value; 
  var myBox2 = document.getElementById('box2').value;
  var result = document.getElementById('result');
  var myResult = parseInt(myBox1) + parseInt(myBox2);

  if(isNaN(myResult))
      myResult = "Please Enter only Numbers!"       

  result.value =  myResult;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/emilvr/73om478x/2/